# ¿Por qué me sale este error al utilizar selenium?Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Tengo el siguiente código y me sale el siguiente error en las linea PATH:

```
Anomalous backslash in string: '\P'. String constant might be missing an r prefix.pylint(anomalous-backslash-in-string)
```

lo que sería en español "Barra invertida anómala en la cadena: '\P'. Es posible que a la constante de cadena le falte un prefijo r.pylint (anomalous-backslash-in-string)".

Cuando voy a ejecutar el código todo normal pero al abrir el navegador y se me cierra de inmediato el navegador, no entiendo porque pasa eso.

Tengo la versión del Google Chrome 85.0.4183.83

```
from selenium import webdriver

PATH = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=PATH)
driver.get('https:/google.es')
```

**Edición**

Sobre la terminal me aparece esto

```
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:58559/devtools/browser/36738aa9-7f39-4939-ad1c-936c9ade2734
```

y el error es el mismo que el de antes en la misma linea

Comment: ¿Será 
PATH = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\chromedriver.exe'?

Comment: Lo acabo de probar asi y me vuelve a suceder lo mismo @CandidMoe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En python con Windows, tienes que cambiar las contrabarras, por barras siempre que pongas cualquier **PATH**. Por lo que tu ejemplo quedaría así:

```
from selenium import webdriver

#Cambiamos las contrabarras por barras
PATH = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=PATH)
driver.get('https:/google.es')
```

Comment: Lo acabo de probar como dices y me vuelve a salir el mismo error

Comment: puedes poner toda la traza del error por favor. Con la linea exactamente que te da el error y todo.

Comment: Sobre la terminal me aparece esto "ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:58559/devtools/browser/36738aa9-7f39-4939-ad1c-936c9ade2734" y  el error es el mismo que el de antes en la misma linea

Comment: Pues la verdad es que no entiendo que puede sucederte, este error no tiene nada que ver con el anterior.

Comment: No pasa nada muchas gracias por ayudarme. Creo que ya se pq es. Es debido a q tengo mal instalado el geckodriver